# Sending events to event hub from APIM result in unauthorized when using managed identity

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-eventhub, azure-managed-identity

I am attempting to setup an APIM endpoint that sends messages to an event hub. I also want to use managed identities in order to authorize the APIM with the event hub. Note that all resources lie in the same subscription. The setup is as follows:

- I have an APIM instance with a system assigned identity. This identity has been giving the contributor role on a subscription level.
- I have an event hub namespace and event hub, which is setup to receive the events.
- I have created an API + operation, that generates events, based on the payload and sends them to the event hub. The example below just sends some hardcoded body, I want to get it working before working on the payload.

The policy for the operation looks like this:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://eventhubs.azure.net" output-token-variable-name="msi-access-token" ignore-error="false" />
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(String.Concat("Bearer ",(string)context.Variables["msi-access-token"]))</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>{ "Event":"apim-using -aad token", "TrustedService":"AAD" }</set-body>
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://[someeventhub].servicebus.windows.net" />
        <rewrite-uri template="/input/messages?api-version=2014-01" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Whenever I try to test the operation though, I get a 401 Unauthorized.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 SubCode=40100: Unauthorized : Unauthorized access for 'Send' operation on endpoint 'sb://[someeventhub].servicebus.windows.net/input/messages?api-version=2014-01'. Tracking Id: [X]
```

Looking at the trace, the authentication requests looks like it went through okay:

```
authentication-managed-identity (0.365 ms)
{
    "message": "Obtaining managed identity token using clientId:[X] AAD Authority:https://login.windows.net/[A] for https://eventhubs.azure.net audience succeeded.",
    "errorResponse": null
}
```

Am I missing something here? It seems to me that there might be something with an app registration? I don't understand why though - the app already has contributor rights for the subscription. Does it need anything else?

As a final note, the forward request looks like this:

```
forward-request (0.129 ms)
    {
    "message": "Request is being forwarded to the backend service. Timeout set to 300 seconds",
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://[someeventhub].servicebus.windows.net/input/messages?api-version=2014-01",
        "headers": [
            {
                // A bunch of headers
            },
            {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "value": "Bearer [A VALID JWT TOKEN]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the app already has contributor rights for the subscription. Does it need anything else?

Yes; The "Contributor" role gives the app access to the Azure resource management plane for operations like creating a new Event Hub but does not grant access for the data plane.

The app will need to have either "Event Hubs Data sender" or "Event Hubs Data owner" role in order to publish events.  *(see: [Authorize access to Event Hubs resources using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com//azure/event-hubs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-azure-event-hubs) for more context)*

Comment: How come my personal user can send events to the event hub though? When I access the IAM panel and press "View my access", I see that I only have the contributor role. But I can still log onto the "Service bus explorer" and send events to that event hub, from my own user. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: My understanding is that interactive accounts with ownership roles are treated differently than AAD App accounts and have many of the data plane roles implicitly associated.   That said, we're out of my area of expertise, so please take that as a non-authoritative statement.